# How to track previous guesses

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a student in Australia studying Digitronics. My code for a game of Minesweeper works, but there are a few flaws. The one that I can't seem to fix is this:
There is a countdown timer, that works by multiplying the rows and the columns, and then taking the number of mines away. However, the player can cheat the timer by entering in the same 'safe' square over and over again. I can't figure out how to put all the guesses into a list, and then add each guess in one by one, but I get the basic principle. 
**How do I add them into lists so the countdown timer can't be cheated like this?**

```
# Simple Minesweeper - but not so simple anymore
# Version 3.0
# 20/9/17 - 25/10/17

from random import randint      # so there is a random mine placement
import time     # so I can delay the game
import sys      # so I can quit the game at any time

# Starts the loop for the game
play = True
while play == True:

    ##########################################
    #### Lists and Variables Created Here ####
    ##########################################

    # opens the board for use
    board = [] 

    # opens the mines list, currently empty so it can be altered later. 
    mines = []

    # determines the rows on the board
    board_row = 0

    # determines the adjacent mines
    adj = 0

    # sets a variable to be used later in the check_ans() function
    wrong = 0

    #determines the amount of rows on the board
    while True:
        board_row = int(input("For a square board, how many rows and columns? (5 min, 10 max):"))
        if board_row > 10:
            print("That is too high. Please enter another!")
        elif board_row < 5:
            print("That is too small. Please enter another!")
        else:
            break

    # adds mines for a larger board
    if board_row >= 8:
        for i in range(15):
            mines.append([randint(0,board_row-1), randint(0, board_row-1)])

    # adds smaller mines for a smaller board
    elif board_row >= 5:
        for i in range(10):
            mines.append([randint(0,board_row-1), randint(0, board_row-1)])

    # creates the 'x's to display on the minewsweeper board
    for i in range(board_row):
        board.append(["x"] * board_row)

    ##############################
    #### Functions Start Here ####
    ##############################

    # creates the rows
    def draw_board(board):
        for i in board:
             print(" |".join(i))
             print("-" * (board_row*3-1))

    # check the answers
    def check_ans():
        if row >= board_row or col >= board_row:
            print("That number is too high. The order goes 1 to ", board_row)
            wrong = 1
        else:
            wrong = 0      

    # defines the adjacent mines, by checking each of the surrounding squares, one
    # by one
    def adj_mines(r, c, adj):
        adj = 0
        if [r+1, c] in mines:
            adj += 1
        if [r+1, c+1] in mines:
            adj += 1
        if [r+1, c-1] in mines:
            adj += 1
        if [r, c+1] in mines:
            adj += 1
        if [r, c-1] in mines:
            adj += 1
        if [r-1, c+1] in mines:
            adj += 1
        if [r-1, c] in mines:
            adj += 1
        if [r-1, c-1] in mines:
            adj += 1
        return adj

    def Intro_to_game():
        print('Hello. This is a game of Minesweeper.')
        print('On each turn, select the number of the row and column that you wish to ')
        print('uncover, and press enter. If a number appears, ')
        print('it indicates how many bombs are in the ')
        print('surrounding eight tiles (\'x\'s). To let you know how')
        print('many tiles you have left to uncover, there is a ')
        print('countdown before each turn. You cannot flag bombs, only avoid them.')
        print('Enjoy, and good luck!')

    # defines number of moves required to beat the game, as
    # there is no flagging function. 

    moves = (((board_row) * (board_row) - int(len(mines))))


    ##################################
    #### Main Program Starts Here ####
    ##################################

    draw_board(board)

    # This uses a function to determine how many cells are left to
    # clear the board, as there is no way to flag. This makes the
    # game significantly harder, as you have to keep track in your
    # head of where the bombs are. 
    Intro_to_game()
    while True:
        print('===================================')
        print("Cells to clear: " + str(moves))

        # This part enters in the rows and columns. However, although
        # the lists typically start at 0, the program has to subtract
        # one from the different imputs to put them in the right place

        row = (int(input("Row: ")) - 1)

        # This part doesn't allow the player to enter
        # a number that is higher than the board range
        while row >= board_row:
            print('That is not in the board range')
            row = (int(input("Row: ")) -1) 

        col = (int(input("Col: ")) - 1)

        # This part doesn't allow the player to enter
        # a number that is higher than the board range

        while col >= board_row:
            print('That is not in the board range')
            col = (int(input("Col: ")) -1)              

        # checks to see if there is a bomb in the called field, if not,
        # then it repeats. If there is a bomb, it shows, "Sorry, but you
        # have blown up." Then it asks if they player would like to play
        # again. 
        check_ans()

        if wrong != 1:
            if [row, col] in mines:
                break
            else:
                board[row][col] = str(adj_mines(row,col,0))
                moves = moves - 1
        draw_board(board)
        if moves == 0:
            print("You have won!")
            time.sleep(2)
            sys.exit
    print("Sorry, but you have blown up :(")

    # Although unconventional, this little bit processes the
    # request to play again. If yes, it breaks the loop, and
    # goes back to the start. If no, sys.exit quits the game

    print("Would you like to play again? (Yes or No)")
    play_again = input()
    if play_again == 'Yes':
        continue
    if play_again == 'Y':
        continue
    if play_again == 'yes':
        continue
    if play_again == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you never check if the position is already revealed. You could do it by checking for the initial 'x':

```
# ...
    if wrong != 1:
        if [row, col] in mines:
            break
        elif board[row][col] != 'x':
            print('This square is already revealed!! Try again')
        else:
            board[row][col] = str(adj_mines(row,col,0))
            moves = moves - 1
# ...
```